# pyautogui "move" and "press" function does not run for some unknown reason

Tags: python, python-3.x, pyautogui

I am building a client which receives commands from a server. (A "TeamViewer" type program)
The server sends keypress events and mouse coordinates and the client runs them.
although currently debugging is running on the same computer, I expect to see some mouse movement when I use `pyautogui.move(x,y)` or `pyautogui.press(char)`. No movement is seen and no keyboard press is happening.
The function `exe()` is running on a thread and is working properly (printing the coordinates works fine).

Why does `pyautogui.move(x,y)` or `pyautogui.press(char)` work is this code?

```py
def exe():        
        while True:
            if executeQ:
                command = executeQ.get()               
                commandlist = command.split('\n')

                char = commandlist[0]
                x = commandlist[1]           #getting command
                y = commandlist[2]
            
                    
                try:
                    print(f'Typing - {char}')
                    pyautogui.press(char)
                except:
                    pass

                try:
                    print(f'Moving to - {x},{y}')
                    pyautogui.move(x,y)
                except:
                    print("OUT OF BOUNDS / SAME POSOTION")
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try to convert `x` and `y` to integers.

```py
x = int(commandlist[1])
y = int(commandlist[2])
```